# Error:Could not read cache value from '/Users/gsp/.gradle/daemon/2.10/registry.bin'

Tags: android, macos, android-gradle-plugin

am working on android project on macbook, of recent i just emptied my recycle bin but when i sync my project i get the following error 
**Error:Could not read cache value from **/Users/gsp/.gradle/daemon/2.10/registry.bin'**

****i know this question has been asked before  and i have read through the solutions **but i have failed to locate location of registry.bin fil**e now my question is 
**how do i delete the "registry.bin" file**  as  it has been suggested****

i have tried checking for "**.gradle**" in my user folder but in its not there

Answer (score 7):

You have the path in your error message.

1. Open Finder
2. Press Cmd+Shift+G
3. Type in ~/.gradle and press enter
4. Then go to the "daemon" folder and delete the folder named "2.10"
5. Rebuild/sync your project

Answer (score 1):

just go **/Users/gsp/.gradle/daemon/2.10** directory and delete all files in that directory. that should work...

Answer (score 0):

you should delete only that directory that mention in file path like 2.10 or 4.1 etc.

for example android studio giving `error like: Error:Could not read cache value from 'C:\Users\User_Name\.gradle\daemon\4.1\registry.bin'`.

And manually browse the given directory `"C:\Users\User_Name\.gradle\daemon"` 
and delete folder 4.1.
 after that, you should go android studio and click on sync gradle icon.