# Jenkins Gradle failure with Could not write cache value to '/home/bldadm/.gradle/daemon/4.8/registry.bin'

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I saw some previous posted questions and their possible answers like [Error:Could not read cache value from '/Users/gsp/.gradle/daemon/2.10/registry.bin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381726/errorcould-not-read-cache-value-from-users-gsp-gradle-daemon-2-10-registry-b) but even after deleting the folder 4.8 and rebuild and sync still getting the same error, I don't know what else the problem could be. any hint for help is appreciated. My error is could not write not could not read not even sure if deleting the version folder was a solution in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone have the same issue, I found out the problem was I can't write on the bldadm, I just have to fill it up which I don't have the right to do, then after discussing the issue with one of our cloud engineers they said The home dir needs to be increased, and they did which solved the issue,

Answer (score 0):

There is another option.
you can delete the daemon directory that under .gradle (in my case I changed her name).
this is how it work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).